# Binding table column to a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Good day, just a quick question:
I would like to bind a table to a checkboxlist control, so I did this in the Page_Load method:

```
CBL_categ.DataSource = FilmsAccess.Pop_check();
CBL_categ.DataBind();
```

I specify that `Pop_check` returns a table of one column.

When I run, instead of the values in that column, I see `"System.Data.DataRowView"` a number of times, with the check boxes. I also tried:
`CBL_categ.DataSource = FilmsAccess.Pop_check().Column[0];` but it gives this error: `Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.`

Thanks a lot. Anna

EDIT: Here's the Pop_check() method at request:

```
public static DataTable Pop_check()
        {
            DbCommand com = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = "Catalog_CBL";
            DataTable table = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(com);
            return table;

        }
```

Comment: Please post your code for Pop_check()

Comment: try this FilmsAccess.Pop_check().Rows.Items[0]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not possible to add Items after Rows in this context. Items doesn't show in autocomplete after Rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ASCX file bind following two field, preferably by name

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblMyList" runat="server" 
   DataTextField="ID" DataValueField="ID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Thanks Gregory, could you be a little more explicit please? Where should I add that? I'm a beginner.

Comment: 1) I'm guessing you're in ASP.NET, not windows.  2) Either way, in Design view you could type them into the Properties of the control.